# How can I extract and compare specific number values from a file with tcl?

Tags: file, file-io, compare, line, tcl

I would like to read specific value numbers and compare them from a file in tcl. For example:

```
node4 time: 3.03 PositionX :34.596   PositionY: 200.34
node5 time: 6.02 PositionX :4.50   PositionY: 30.234
```

I need to read **ONLY** the node number, like node4 and 3.03 and 200.34 as well
and so on for each line, then print them or compare them later. How I can do that in tcl?

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on [scan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/scan.htm).

For example: (do this in a loop)

```
scan $line "node%i time: %f PositionX :%f   PositionY: %f" nodenr time posx posy
```

Then you can use the variables `nodenr`, `time`, `posx` and `posy`

For the file part, you only need [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [read](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/read.htm) and [close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm). See this [Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/tutorial/Tcl24.html). For splitting the entire file into a list (that can be used with [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm)) use [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)

Comment: The other possible tool is a regular expression, but `scan` is exactly the right tool for this sort of thing.